# foreach with a simple variable?

Tags: php

I have a page which look like this :

```
<?php $items = isset($_GET['id']) ? gg::getItemID($_GET['id']) : gg::getAllItems();?>
...code
...code
<?php foreach ($items as $item):?>
...code
...code
...code
<?php endforeach;?>
...code
```

The method `getItemID()` will fetch a specific row in a table and return it, whereas `getAllItems()` will fetch all of them.

However `foreach` won't work with `$items = gg::getItemID($_GET['id']` and I don't really know how I could set up a "universal way" to make it work whether `getItemID()` or `getAllItems()` is called.

Is there a simple way to do this ?

Comment: insert in an array like .. $items = isset($_GET['id']) ? array('0' => gg::getItemID($_GET['id'])) : gg::getAllItems();  ?

Comment: So what do you actually by "won't work"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just make an array on the fly:

```
$items = isset($_GET['id']) ? array(gg::getItemID($_GET['id'])) : gg::getAllItems();
//                            ^ use array() to force it to be an array
```

Note that you do not need to specify an index (like `'0' => ...`) as one of the comments indicates. The element will automatically get the index `0` (integer).

Also, be sure you handle the `$_GET['id']` value carefully. Depending on what `gg::getItemID()` does, you may have a [SQL injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection) vulnerability.

Comment: Aaaah thank you ! I was (wrongfully) trying to set $items as an array (like $items[] = isset...) but then it wouldn't work for `gelAllItems()`

Comment: However what do you mean by vulnerability ? I'm getting started and working locally at the moment so I don't know much about SQL security yet. All I'm doing as a "security" is using the function `mysqli_real_escape_string` for every sql request, if that's enough. I'll check out your link, thank you !

Comment: @eloism Glad to help! About the vulnerability: please see [the link I shared above](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection). If the data is passed directly into a database query and the URL is something like `http://yoursite.com/page?id=1; DELETE FROM items; -- `, for example, you might lose an entire table. Clever hackers can use things like this to destroy data or even find ways to take over the site. You have to be *very, very careful* anytime you do anything with user input.